# Grails dynamic dropdown add selected value for edit.gsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamic dropdown on my _form.gsp that is render in both create and edit gsp. It works fine, but I want the selected value be displayed on the edit.gsp.

_form.gsp

```
    <g:select name="plant.id" id="plant" from="${MCM.MGPlant.list(sort:'member')}" value="${MGMatriceInstance?.plant?.id}" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"
             onchange='loadCostCenter(this.value);'/> 
    <g:select id="costCenter" name="costCenter.id" from="${[]}" optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"/>


<script type="text/javascript">        
       function loadCostCenter(init)
            {
                var root="${resource()}";
                var plantid = document.getElementById('plant').value;
                var url = root+'/MGMatrices/findCostCenterForPlant?plantId='+plantid;

                jQuery('#costCenter').load(url);
            }           
</script>
```

Comment: try in plant select, use value attribute

Comment: I added it and it work. I also want the second dropdown to display the selected value also. But it didn't work there.

Comment: see the updated code in my answer field

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, when click the country in select ,it displays locaions of the country in ajax. Replace plant in the place of country and cost in the place of locations.

In _temp1 template ,put only plant and div(for cost dropdown) and one textbox(to store cost id that is come from edit).

create another template for cost. that will display costs when plant is selected in dynamically.

in edit action, u have to send plantInstance and costInstance to view.

In create.gsp and edit.gsp

```
...........
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        getSelectedCountry();
    });

    function getSelectedCountry(){
        var selectedCountry = jQuery("#country").val();
        var locationId = jQuery("#locationId").val();
        alert(locationId)
        if(selectedCountry != ''){
            if(locationId!=''){
                ${remoteFunction (controller: 'country', action: 'locations', params: '\'countryId=\' + selectedCountry+\'&locationId=\'+locationId', update: 'updateLocation')}

            }

            else
            ${remoteFunction (controller: 'country', action: 'locations', params: '\'countryId=\' + selectedCountry', update: 'updateLocation')}
        }
    }
</script>

......
            <g:render template="form" />
......
```

in _form.gsp:

```
<g:select name="country" id="country" from="${com.ard.Country.list()}" 
optionKey="id" noSelection="${['': 'Select']}" value="${countryInstance?.id}"
             onchange='getSelectedCountry();'/> 

 <div id="updateLocation"></div>  

 <g:textField name="locationId" value="${locationInstance.id}"/>
```

in _locations.gsp

```
<g:select id="location" name="location" from="${locations}" value="${locationInstance.id}"optionKey="id" noSelection="${[null: 'Select One...']}"/>
```

in controller action,

```
 def locations(){
            def country = Country.get(params.countryId)
            def locations = country.locations
                    def loc
                    if(params.locationId)
              loc = Location.get(params.locationId)
            render(template:"locations",model[locations:locations,locationInstance:loc])
    }
```

in edit action:

```
edit(){

......

render(view:"edit"  ,model:[countryInstance:country,locationInstance:locationInstance]

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. The jQuery function is not called. Is there any workaround on my code?

Comment: yes i did. An there's no need to add a textbox for the cost id.

Comment: It need. Without this we cant display selected value in cost on edit page.

Comment: in edit , we have the cost and plant. According to the plant, plant value displayed in drop down . But we couldn't display cost in beginning. So we maintain cost in hidden and get the cost in hidden and we displayed it in cost

Comment: How can i get the value of country and locationInstance in the edit()?

Comment: i have one dout.Sorry for late doubt.One plant have one cost right?Why we have to choose plant then cost center display?Pls clarify my doubt

Comment: No its one to many relationship. One plant has a lot of cost center.

Comment: Plant hasmany cost center and cost center belongsTo plant.right?

Comment: For me, country hasmany locations.location belongsTo country.

Comment: I am using location's create and edit page. In edit aaction ,i got locationInstance and using locationInstance i can get country like locationInstance.country.So i can pass locationInstance and country Instance from edit

Comment: I don't have code in create and edit in the controller. Its scaffold.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39730/discussion-between-anantha-and-jeka)

Comment: see the chat  by clicking  continue this discussion in chat

Comment: Hi i have my code now in edit action. but the cost value is still not displayed on the dropdown. please help.

Comment: no no.domain classes stucture.and in which domain view you are using for this.i want all the details.then only i can help you.